# Webdav on Windows server 2012 enable doc versions

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webdav

I installed WebDav on windows server 2012 that i use as document repository . I have my ASP.NET app that manage the documents where my users can edit docs . also my web (on different server) can embed a document into one of these documents on WebDav server .
I ran into a scenario where the embedded doc is corrupted and cannot be open . This where i realized that I have no previous version on WebDav server of this document.

My question : To activate document version control with WebDav on windows is basically activating previous version on file system in windows ? or there is another way WebDav will keep track of the previous versions.

Thank you.